# Compare intensity pixel value Vec3b in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I have a 3 channel `Mat` image, type is `CV_8UC3`.
I want to compare, in a loop, the intensity value of a pixel with its neighbours and then set `0` or `1` if the neighbour is greater or not. 
I can get the intensity calling `Img.at<Vec3b>(x,y)`.

But my question is: how can I compare two `Vec3b`?

Should I compare pixels value for every channel (BGR or `Vec3b[0]`, `Vec3b[1]` and `Vec3b[2]`), and then merge the three channels results into a single `Mat` object?

Comment: Yes you need to compare 3 channels seperately.

Comment: _intensity_ is a single value (and so you matrix is single channel), not a BGR triplet. So, what do you want to compare?

Comment: I want to compare intensity represented by CV_8UC3.

Comment: So you want to compare the intensity of each channel separately? Maybe taking the max among the 3 channels? Or you want to define a comparison operation on `Vec3b` so you can compare them? It's really up to you, and what you need to do. If you _clarify_ what's your final goal we can provide a _clear_ answer.

Comment: As you can see, the proposed answers boils down to comparing single values, not triplets. Again, please clarify your final goal.

Comment: Ok Miki. I have to create and modify the original Census transform. So, in a nxn window, I have to compare the central pixel with the others. If the central is greater I set 1. Finally the results are concatenated. I'm sorry that I was not so clear but I'm almost new to OpenCV.

Comment: _If the central is greater_ **of what**? Census transform is defined on a single channel image, which is usually the grayscale or your color image.

Comment: There's a loop comparing the central pixel with the other pixel in the window. What if I consider the color image?

Comment: If you consider the color image, you need to define how to compare two RGB triplets. That's up to you, and this is the point that is still missing to provide a correct answer. The Census transform is defined on a single channel only. Once you define how to compare the triplets, you can project the 3 channel image onto a single channel image, and compare single channels only.

Comment: Alternatively, you can perform census transform over all three channels of the RGB color space independently, and then concatenating the results together. The number of bits required to store census value will be three times more as in case of grayscale images. i.e in case of 3x3 census window the value would be 3*2^3 = 24 bits.

Comment: @Kornel and this is still a comparison on single channels :D. Then in this case you don't need 24 bits. 8 bits are more then enough. But more on this only if OP asks :D

Comment: I've found that I have to compare the pixels using census transform and the concatenate the results in the three channels separately. Sorry but my documentation was not so clear.

Comment: @Kornel, I have to use a 5x5 window. I will have 24 bits for every pixel and channel. Do you know hot to store these three bytes?

Comment: well, the 24 bits are the neigbours under the 5x5 window. `2^i=0` if the intensity of the i'th neigbour less then the intensity of the centre pixel otherwise the bit is `1` (`i=0..23`).

Comment: @Kornel, how to best store them? I was thinking of a Mat with three channels to store the bytes, but a byte would have been right for every pixel. Now that a single pixel in a channel has 3 bytes? Do I have to use another structure?

Answer (score 0):

Me again :)

If you want to compare (greater or less) two RGB values you need to project the 3-dimensional RGB space onto a plane or axis.

Of course, there are many possibilities to do this, but an easy way would be to use the HSV color space. The hue (`H`), however, is not appropriate as a linear order function because it is circular (i.e. the value 1.0 is identical with 0.0, so you cannot decide if 0.5 > 0.0 or 0.5 < 0.0). However, the saturation (`S`) or the value (`V`) are appropriate projection functions for your purpose:

- If you want to have colored pixels "larger" than monochrome pixels, you will prefer `S`.
- If you want to have lighter pixels larger than darker pixels, you will probably prefer `V`.
- Also any combination of `S` and `V` would be a valid projection function, e.g. `S+V`.

Comment: Me again :D. This falls into the case that you compare single values, not triplets. As the question is still unclear now, since OP is not clarifying the final goal, I'd wait a little before posting some random guesses.To sum up, this answer is somehow valid, but we actually can't know if this answer the question.

Comment: yes, I'm totally agree, I only wanted to target that the RGB space is not enough structured to compare intensity values so in any case you have to find another way to do the comparison

Comment: And that's why I didn't downvoted :D. But you _may_ be wrong. For example, if OP is trying to get something similar to Dark Channel Prior, you have to work on RGB space. But, unless the question is made more clear, there's not much we can do :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want a measure to calculate distance/similarity between two Vec3b pixels. This can be reflected to the general problem of finding distance between two vectors in an n-mathematical space.

One of the famous measures (and I think this is what you're asking for), is the Euclidean distance.

If you are using Opencv then you can simply use:

```
cv::Vec3b a(1, 1, 1);
cv::Vec3b b(5, 5, 5);
double dist = cv::norm(a, b, CV_L2);
```

You can refer to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) for reading about cv::norm and its options.

Edit: If you are doing this to measure color similarity, it's recommended to use the LAB color space as it's proved that Euclidean distance in LAB space is a good approximation for human perception of colors.

Edit 2: I see what you mean, for this you can get the magnitude of each vector and then compare them, something like this:

```
    double a_magnitude = cv::norm(a, CV_L2);
    double b_magnitude = cv::norm(b, CV_L2);
    if(a_magnitude > b_magnitude)
      // do something
    else
      // do something else.
```

Comment: See my comment on @Kornel answer.

Comment: As for @Kornel answer, there's nothing wrong. It's just that now we **don't** know what OP wants. So any answer may be correct or not. It's just not worth answering. By answering, we are also encouraging OP to not clarify the question.

Comment: Dummy me :) .. I thought OP is the one who was commenting. I totally agree with you, I instantly suggested that what he is looking for a color based similarity measure. He might be asking for something totally different.